# TooManyEvaluationsException when calculating integral of high-order polynomial using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, apache, math, apache-commons

I'm using Apache Math to calculate the integrals of some high order polynomials (degree 40 with many terms) using this code:

```
simpsonIntegrator.integrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE, uf, 0, 100);
```

However I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.exception.TooManyEvaluationsException: illegal state: maximal count (2,147,483,647) exceeded: evaluations
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration.BaseAbstractUnivariateIntegrator.computeObjectiveValue(BaseAbstractUnivariateIntegrator.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration.TrapezoidIntegrator.stage(TrapezoidIntegrator.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration.SimpsonIntegrator.doIntegrate(SimpsonIntegrator.java:112)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration.BaseAbstractUnivariateIntegrator.integrate(BaseAbstractUnivariateIntegrator.java:280)
```

Can Apache Math calculate integrals this complex?

Example code below:

```
double[] coefficients = new double[] { 120.38735982092798, -7.432833370751281, -4.197678241326614,
            1.935518550792998, -0.2717208510603644, 0.010272539175964844, 0.0014583652338223108,
            -2.3545889963370238E-4, 1.7089604714800273E-5, -7.940595470645408E-7, 2.60400363658514E-8,
            -6.295312573702475E-10, 1.147109622979095E-11, -1.591490268563359E-13, 1.683228910193124E-15,
            -1.3473343508219034E-17, 8.022211284926259E-20, -3.4419978519650748E-22, 1.0053973045968942E-24,
            -1.7889385990234268E-27, 1.4626500062261931E-30 };

PolynomialFunction p = new PolynomialFunction(coefficients);

UnivariateFunction uf = (UnivariateFunction) new PolynomialFunction(p.multiply(p).getCoefficients());

// integrate regression
SimpsonIntegrator integrator = new SimpsonIntegrator();
System.out.println("answer: " + (Math.PI * integrator.integrate(Integer.MAX_VALUE, uf, 0, 100)));
```

It's OK if it takes a long time to solve, I just need an answer eventually.

Comment: Post complete code

Comment: Do you know what number is interger max in java?

Comment: I've added some example code. Also, I'm not sure what "evaluations" from "max evaluations" means. I'm assuming it's a way to break out of a calculation if it's too lengthy.  In this case, I want an answer no matter how long it takes.

Comment: Did you look at the size of the polynomial value at `x=100`? What are the error bounds? I suspect that it is impossible to meet the absolute error bound. -- How about symbolic integration, which is simple for polynomials?